# Splitting deques inside vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to deal with a very strange problem. I don't have much experience with STL containers so their mechanics are a big mystery for me. Ok, back to main topic. I need to create a vector of deques and then split every existing deque inside this vector in half. Each half will create seperate deque from now on.
I'm expecting something like this:

> vector{ deque{1,2,3,4,5} } -----> vector { deque{1,2,3}, deque{4,5} }

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector< std::deque<int> > vector_of_deques;
    vector_of_deques.push_back( std::deque<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} );

    std::deque<int> deque = *(vector_of_deques.begin());
    int split_position;

    if (deque.size() % 2 == 0)
        split_position = deque.size() / 2;
    else 
        split_position = int(deque.size() / 2) + 1;

    vector_of_deques.emplace_back( deque.begin() + split_position, deque.end() );
    deque.erase( deque.begin() + split_position, deque.end() );

    for (auto i: vector_of_deques) {
        for (auto j: i)
            std::cout << j << ", ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>
> 4, 5,

Expected:

> 1, 2, 3,
>
> 4, 5,

I have not a single idea what's going on. Can someone explain me why my way of thinking about those containers is wrong? It would be a great help for me.

Comment: `*(vector_of_deques.begin());` is more succinctly expressed as `vector_of_deques.front();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
std::deque<int> deque = *(vector_of_deques.begin());
```

You are making a copy of the deque, when really what you want is a `std::deque<int>&`.  As it is, when your code does this:

```
deque.erase( deque.begin() + split_position, deque.end() );
```

You're erasing from the copy and not changing your original vector.

Comment: Oh God... Of course that's the problem. Thank you. Now I can go back to work.